# Whats the difference between creating a div as a string versus using createElement()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know there is some functions made available to creating a node div with createElement(), but is there any other differences? performance? usability? etc...

**String div**

```
$('body').append("<div>foo</div>");
```

*versus*

**Creating a node div**

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
var divContent = document.createTextNode("foo");
newDiv.appendChild(divContent);
$('body').append(newDiv);
```

Comment: It would just improve a bit of performance as you are avoiding the creation of 2 new nodes. This would be an issue if you creating hundreds of elements on the fly. Otherwise the performance impact will be minimal.

Comment: @Sushanth--: What would improve performance? `<div>foo</div>` doesn’t avoid creation of nodes.

Comment: I just realized that append() was a jquery function and appendChild() doesn't convert string divs into actual divs.

Comment: document.createElement() adds the element to the DOM, meaning it's usable through js, but you don't have to actually append it to the document element, which can be needed i.e if the element is an image that you only want to be drawn on a canvas, but not rendered in the page, or if you need to add some eventListeners to it before it is rendered etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the string (example 1) is actually better performing than creating nodes (second example).  This is because jQuery already does what is in your node example for you, so you're sort of doing double work in the second example.

Because people didn't seem to believe me, here's a simple benchmark I just made and ran, doing 10,000 operations of each method:

```
var start = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    $('body').append("<div>foo</div>");
}
console.log('Took ' + (performance.now() - start) + ' ms');
```

**Took 70 ms** averaged over 10 tests.

```
var start = performance.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var divContent = document.createTextNode("foo");
    newDiv.appendChild(divContent);
    $('body').append(newDiv);
}
console.log('Took ' + (performance.now() - start) + ' ms');
```

**Took 110 ms** averaged over 10 tests.

Keep in mind that this is all dependent on browser, jquery version, other javascript on the page, etc.  That said, if you're appending a number of elements to the dom where this performance actually matters I'd be very surprised.

Comment: @minitech I'm pretty sure there is no actual benchmark involved. Just a guess\illusion.

Comment: @Vohuman: Well, it was true that manipulating `innerHTML` in particular was better-performing in older browsers, but I have the distinct impression that it’s not the case in any modern one. jsPerf is down, though, so I’m trying to build my own for now.

Comment: @minitech Yes, jsPerf is down unfortunately. As far as I know jQuery doesn't manipulate the `innerHTML` property here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/349edbd6c53aa93d4fd207d3c0c4c24a7b0314dd/src/manipulation.js#L312

Comment: 1800–2029 ms for the first one for me, 1250–1401 ms for the second one, Chromium 44, jQuery 2.1.4. Test more browsers more times. (And use `performance.now`.)

Comment: I ran the above snippets and got "Took 1311 ms" for the first snippet and 
"Took 1164 ms" for the second one.

Comment: Dates are very imprecise, at least use `performance.now()`. @Vohuman `append` uses `domManip`, which uses `buildFragment`, which uses `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Oriol That's true. `buildFragment` uses `createDocumentFragment` which makes a huge difference performance-wise.

Comment: Interestingly, I got wildly different numbers with performance.now() as @Oriol suggested.  Although I still get the string method (example 1) performing better than the node method (example 2)

Comment: Of course, using either method efficiently is better (appending 10000 elements to a document fragment or 10000 strings to a string and then setting `innerHTML` in one go), having times of about 9 or 10 ms each, and it’s the only case that really matters, as one method versus another used on one element at a time won’t have a noticeable effect in practice.

Comment: I don't think this is really answering the question enough. Looking at how different browsers execute this code might bear more useful information here. While interesting that different browsers give different results, 40ms difference for adding 10000 nodes is going to be considered negligible in most cases.

Comment: You should also consider a third benchmark with `newDiv.textContent = 'foo';`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! Random sidenote: I just became curious about the performance difference between .append() and .appendChild() and it was a much bigger difference in performance. :]